# Select value of xml document with namespace

Tags: xml, xslt, value-of

I have the following XML snippet

```
<aaa>
  <bbb xmlns="http://net.some.address.com">
    <ccc>123321</ccc>
  </bbb>
</aaa>
```

And i want to select the value of `<ccc>` with XSL template, but not able to get it by using

```
<xsl:value-of select="/aaa/bbb/ccc"/>
```

Any ideas how to get the value without changing the input ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Declare the namespace and use it.

```
<xsl:value-of xmlns:a="http://net.some.address.com" select="/aaa/a:bbb/a:ccc"/>
```

- You can pick any prefix you want, it does not have to be `a`.
- You can declare the namespace at any point higher up in the XSLT document. Usually all namespaces are declared at the `<xsl:stylesheet>` level, but as you can see, that's just a convention.